# Iterative quicksort method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a hoare quicksort method that runs iterativly. Im using the Algorithm below. So right now it inputs: 10 7 8 9 1 5 and for example when i run it outputs: 5 7 8 9 1 10 it only switches 2 elements from the array. Why does it stop? Where did i go wrong?

Algorithm:

1. Create arrays left and right of N / 2 elements, where the number of N elements in array a.
2. Assign left [0] to 0 and right [0] to index a last element of array a (N-1). Assign to variable stackpos value 1.
3. Decrease the value of variable stackpos by 1. Give left [stackpos] to l and right [stackpos] to r
4. Assign a variable median value to m . The medians
   must be selected between elements a [l] to a [r].
5. Assign a value of variable l to variable i and assign r to variable j.
6. If a [i] is less than m, increase i.
7. If a [j] is greater than m, reduce j.
8. If the variable i is less than or equal to j then:
   a) Swap elements a [i] and a [j] using the three-cup principle.
   b) Increase i by one.
   c) Reduce j by one.
9. If i is less than or equal to j then return to step 6.
10. If i is less than r then:
    a) Assign left [stackpos] to i.
    b) Give r [stackpos] to r.
    c) Increase the variable stackpos by 1.
11. Assign the value of variable r to variable j.
12. If the variable l is less than r then return to step 4.
13. If the stackpos variable is greater than 0, return to step 3

Code:

```
public static void swap (int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}

public static int median (int []a) {
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(a.length);
    int M = a[rnd];
    return M;
}

private static int partition(int[] a, int i, int M, int j) {
    while (i <= j) {
        while (a[i] < M) {
            i++;
        }
        while (a[j] > M) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(a,i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static int[] secondMethod(int[] a) {
    int N=a.length;
    int left [] = new int [N/2];
    int right [] = new int [N/2];
    left[0]=0;
    right[0]=a[N-1];

    int stackpos = 1;
    stackpos--;
    int I = left[stackpos];
    int r = right[stackpos];

    int M=median(a);

    int i=I;
    int j=r;

    partition(a,i,M,j);

    if (i<=j) {
        while (a[i] < M) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (i<r) { //10.
        left[stackpos]=i;
        right[stackpos]=r;
        stackpos++;
    }
    r=j;  //11.
    if (I<r) {
        while(true) {
            M = median(a);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (stackpos>0) {
        while(true) {
            stackpos--;
            I = left[stackpos];
            r = right[stackpos];
            break;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int []a = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
  a = secondMethod(a);
  System.out.println("result :");
  for (int i = 0; i <  a.length; i++)
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to problems, but upper case `I` is probably supposed to be lower case `L` = `l`. For worst case scenario, left[] and right[] need to be of size N-1 or N. Median needs to choose the median of the current working partition. There should be a loop until stack position is reduced back to zero (or 1?) .

Answer (score 2):

Several things are wrong here.

```
right[0]=a[N-1];   # <-------------- pretty sure this should just be N-1, not a[N-1]
```

The second, maybe even worse thing is that **partition is only called once**.

You need to think this whole thing through. The way you explain your algorithm and the while(true) loops that you immediately break out of make this obvious.

My advice:
Do a recursive quicksort first to familiarize yourself with the algorithm. Also to get out of your iterative mindset. Then familiarize yourself with general methods for turning recursive into iterative methods (stacks, dynamic programming). Then apply what you have learned to quicksort.

If you want to, you can of course always look for iterative Quicksort implementations online. I found one which used a stack instead of using recursion. To be honest, this is a good exercise but I doubt Quicksort really benefits from being made iterative. Other algorithms, however, definitely do, so practice is always good.

Comment: A partially iterative quicksort that only recurses on smaller partitions and loops back for larger partitions reduces stack space complexity to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity remains at O(n^2).